# Не работает проверка вложенного массива mongoose

Tags: node.js, валидация, mongoose

В mongoose имею `Schema`:

```
date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    costs: {
        categories:
        {color: {
                type: [String],
                default: ["green"]
            },
        },
        days: [{
            coments: {
                type: [String],
                maxlength: [100, "Comment too long"],
                required: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Валидация не работает в вложенном массиве

```
coments: {
    type: [String],
    maxlength: [100, "Comment too long"],
    required: true
}
```

Это так  и должно быть? Такая валидация в mongoose не поддерживается?

Comment: а если так: `coments: [{ type: String, maxlength: [100, "Comment too long"], required: true }]`?

Comment: Нет. Я вырезал не нужные данные. Необходимо именно ```coments: {
    type: [String],``` . coments  это массив

Comment: в моём варианте он тоже массив

Comment: Тут видимо надо использовать валидацию для  объектов с использованием вложения схем. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-toObject

Comment: @nörbörnën  Действительно Ваш вариант работает. Огромное спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ дал @nörbörnën

```
coments: [{
  type: String,
  maxlength: [100, "Comment too long"],
  required: true
}]
```

Работает. Огромное спасибо!